# returning values which are duplicated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get all the duplicated records based on :

```
accession_id, 
  check_num,
  procedure_code,
  paid_amt,
```

this query will return the above along with the number of times those fields were repeated.

however, i want to only return those that occur more than once.

```
  select    
  ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY, 
  accession_id, 
  check_num,
  procedure_code,
  paid_amt,
  row_number() 
  over 
  (partition by   accession_id, check_num,procedure_code,paid_amt order by ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY) as occurrence
          from      [MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV].[dbo].[F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_DAILY]         
   where PROCEDURE_CODE is not null
   and PAID_AMT>0
```

when i add the filter condition `occurrence>1` to the above query, i am getting this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Invalid column name 'occurrence'.
```

how can i return the records only if they occur more than once?

Comment: The Invalid column error is because you are trying to use an alias in a `WHERE` clause. If you want to use your alias, then you will need to wrap your query inside another `SELECT`

Comment: thank you very much. can you show me how i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an alias in a `WHERE` clause then you can wrap it in another `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  select ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY, 
    accession_id, 
    check_num,
    procedure_code,
    paid_amt,
    row_number() over (partition by   accession_id, check_num,procedure_code,paid_amt order by ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY) as occurrence
  from      [MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV].[dbo].[F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_DAILY]         
  where PROCEDURE_CODE is not null
     and PAID_AMT>0
) x
WHERE x.occurrence>1
```

Comment: here's the thing. the inner select returns like 10 million rows and the execution takes a long time. how can i speed it up?

Comment: are you planning on using the occurrence for anything else but to filter?  If not, then consider using a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause.

Comment: the user in the other answer suggested this. however as you know partition/over works MUCH faster

Comment: I am aware it is slower, that is why I made it a comment and did not edit my answer.  Do you have any indexes on your table?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try a GROUP BY / HAVING clause:

```
SELECT accession_id, check_num, procedure_code, paid_amt,
       COUNT(ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY) as occurrences 
FROM [MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV].[dbo].[F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_DAILY] 
GROUP BY accession_id, check_num, procedure_code,paid_amt 
HAVING COUNT(ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY) > 1
```

The HAVING clause filter the records after the GROUP BY

Comment: +1 thanks so much for your help, but your method is MUCH MUCH slower than mine

Answer (score 1):

I have *no* idea how your table is indexed, but what about a self left join? It might be worth testing, but I can't imagine it's faster than either of the above methods.  I wouldn't even attempt this unless accession_id and check_num are indexed...

```
Select
  t1.*
from [MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV].[dbo].[F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_DAILY] as t1
left join [MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV].[dbo].[F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_DAILY] as t2
  on t2.accession_id = t1.accession_id
  and t2.check_num = t1.check_num
  and t2.procedure_code = t1.procedure_code
  and t2.paid_amt = t1.paid_amt
where t2.ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY is null
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select accession_id, 
    check_num,
    procedure_code,
    paid_amt,
    COUNT(*) as occurrance
  from      [MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV].[dbo].[F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_DAILY]         
  where PROCEDURE_CODE is not null
     and PAID_AMT>0
     group by  accession_id,check_num,procedure_code,paid_amt
     having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe an alternative...

```
;WITH MoreOne_CTE()
    AS
    (
    SELECT       
        ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY   
    FROM  [MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV].[dbo].[F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_DAILY]     
    GROUP BY 
          accession_id,    
          check_num,   
          procedure_code,   
          paid_amt
    HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1     
    )
SELECT       
        ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY ,    
        accession_id,    
        check_num,   
        procedure_code,   
        paid_amt           
FROM [MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV].[dbo].[F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_DAILY]   x  
WHERE
        PROCEDURE_CODE IS NOT NULL
        AND PAID_AMT>0 
        AND EXISTS 
            (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM MoreOne_CTE y 
                    WHERE x.ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY = y.ACCESSION_PAYMENTS_DAILY_KEY
            )
```

Comment: wrote in SSMS; then copied into SO answer; then highlighted and used the {} button.